# strftime not using locale settings (Python 3)

Tags: python, locale, strftime

I thought the output format of `strftime`is based on the locale settings of your machine / environment.

However in Python 3's IDLE I get the following result when trying to format today's date to the german format of `%d. %B %Y`

```
import locale    
locale.getlocale()
```

> ('de_DE', 'cp1252')

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%d. %B %Y')
```

> '26. Februar**y** 2018'

My expectation: **26. Februar 2018**

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this result. I am getting `26. Februar 2018` using `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')`. Which OS you are using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.6.4 (64 bit)

Comment: Please update your question and include the part of code where you are setting the locale

Comment: I am not setting the locale. Is that a problem? I am trying to find out, why with the default locale (de_DE in my example) strftime produces a wrong output,

Comment: I think so. Can you try with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` to get the locale setting from environment?

Comment: yes, the output is 'German_Germany.1252' - however locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE') gives an 'unsupported locale setting' error

Comment: No keep the second argument empty string `''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165846/discussion-between-evilsmurf-and-bro-grammer).

Comment: See [Python issue 29457](https://bugs.python.org/issue29457).

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue (python 3.6, anaconda virtual environment):

- `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` gives an 'unsupported locale setting' error
- `locale.getlocale()` yields 'de_DE', 'UTF-8' but the datetime was printed in english

The Solution suggested by bro-grammer

> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

worked for me